# Is it safe to declare blocks in init?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I need to call a function that takes a block.  Does it cause a problem if I do so inside of an init method?

```
- (id)initWithObjectThatWantsABlock:(Blar *)blar {
    if ((self = [super init])){

      [blar takeBlock:^{
          NSLog(@"Hi");
      }];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's still just a function, and as long as it doesn't depend on anything that you haven't initialised, it should be fine.